# Return a value to String.replace from within a callback function

Tags: javascript

I want to return a value to `String.replace` from within a callback function.
Typing this and posting the code makes me realize how dumb that is.

But, I was hoping there is a way I can achieve the same concept with code that actually works. I feel like it's right in front of me I just can't grasp it.

```
content.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (a, b) { 

  recurse(b, function(content2) {
    return content2;
  });

});
```

Comment: Do you mean that, inside the `String.replace` callback, you're doing something asynchronously which also has a callback? You'll have to find a way to force that second action to be synchronous (some sort of loop should work).

Comment: Much better way of phrasing it. I was having a hard time with the title. Thanks for the loop hint I think I'm on the right track now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got your meaning, but if you intend to return something from the inner function to the outer one, you should be after something like this:

```
content.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (a, b) { 

  return recurse(b, function(content2) {
    return content2;
  });

});
```

Comment: I was writing this solution. :(

Comment: I think `recurse` would be async call, it will not just return `content2`.

Comment: Correct Kabie recurse passes it's callback to a few other async functions as well. Double return doesn't work.

Comment: I guess `recurse` may be just a loop, not necessarily asynchronous. But you are right about what is returned. It will return whatever is returned by `recurse` and not by the anonymous function. Hard to tell without seeing the definition of `recurse`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'r looking for expressions in replacements:

```
function replacer(matchedSubstring, p1, p2, offset, totalString) {
  return p2 + ' ' + p1.toUpperCase();
}

newString = oldString.replace(/(\w+)\s(\w+)/, replacer);
```

Please mind that the number of groups in the RegExp and the number of parameters in the replacer's argument list (here: p1, p2) have to match.

See String.replace() at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

Answer (score 0):

You can implement some (probably awful) "locking" concept. I use the term "locking" loosely here. Regardless, it'll force your code into being synchronous.

```
content.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, function (a, b) { 

  var myFakeLock = false;
  var outputToReplace = null;

  var otherCallback = function(someInput) {
      ... // do some stuff here
      outputToReplace = someCalculationResult;
      myFakeLock = true; // last line!
  };

  // Call asynchronous function
  someFunctionWithCallback(otherCallback);

  // Busy-wait until our callback completes
  while (!myFakeLock) { }

  return outputToReplace;
});
```

I didn't take any care to form a proper closure or anything, so some modification may be needed.

In this solution, the `String.replace` callback will not return until all of the asynchronous calculation is complete. Be careful how you're using this. You don't want to lock the UI thread this way; call it from some other thread.